# Facebook Ratings image in feed & timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have an **ActionType** on Facebook as Ratings (integer type)

How can I instruct Facebook to show ratings as images ( stars in Open Graph timeline & feed view)?

Or rephrasing. How does ***spotify*** manage to show the play icon in the feed? I haven’t seen an option to link images to an ActionType.

[image]

Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook integrate a built in `song` object type for Open Graph. Spotify use this built in type, and Facebook is adding the "play" icon next to song name.

**So, adding a small action icon is not an option you can set up yourself.**

---

*You can checkout more about built in object type here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/builtin/ (Although `song` isn't yet in this list)*

*There's no full page about `song` object type, but the object is listed here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/ (and available through your dashboard)*

Comment: Should be mentioned, that song/listen is only available to whitelisted apps at the moment.